# How fix build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Connected my module and in `build.gradle` write next:

```
plugins {
    id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint")
    kotlin("jvm")
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly(kotlin("stdlib"))
    compileOnly(kotlin("reflect"))
    compileOnly(kotlin("script-runtime"))
    compileOnly("com.pinterest.ktlint:ktlint-core:0.34.2")
}
```

and get next error:

> startup failed: build file
>   '/home/vadimm/AndroidStudioProjects/homework/target-list/custom_ktlint_rules/build.gradle':
>   3: only id(String) method calls allowed in plugins {} script block
>
> See
>   https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block
>   for information on the plugins {} block
>
> @ line 3, column 5.
>          kotlin("jvm")
>          ^
>
> 1 error

Also tried write smth like this:
`apply plugin: 'kotlin'` or

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin'
}
```

but it is not successful

Comment: kotlin("jvm") makes the issue

Comment: Please try with apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' outside and below the plugins {} block. It should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved with next solution:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies {
    compileOnly("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib")
    compileOnly("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    compileOnly("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime")
    compileOnly("com.pinterest.ktlint:ktlint-core:0.34.2")
}
```

kotlin("jvm") is Gradle kotlin-dsl syntax. For common Gradle syntax use apply plugin: 'kotlin'
kotlin("..") is also from Gradle kotlin-dsl

Comment: This doesn't work. The Kapt needs to be in id: format.

Answer (score 79):

> I have faced similar issue. Following solution works for me. Good Luck!!

```
plugins {
    kotlin("kapt")
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
}
```

to

```
plugins {
  id("kotlin-kapt")
  id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")          
}
```

Comment: Can you explain / link to doc explaining the syntax change that was made here

Answer (score 21):

If anyone runs into this error while trying to use Kotlin DSL and wants to keep it: make sure your file is `build.gradle.kts`, not `build.gradle`

Answer (score 1):

I faced this with the kotlin kapt, I edited this:

```
plugins {
id ("kotlin-kapt")
}
```

to this:

```
plugins {
id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

And it worked just fine.